# Connecting to Azure service bus through a proxy server using Java SDK 0.9.7

Tags: java, azure, proxy, azureservicebus

There was a question asked related to my question by another user 'sjohnston' :

Asking again since the answer was not correct.

[Can I set a proxy for Azure service bus connections in Java SDK 0.9.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922666/can-i-set-a-proxy-for-azure-service-bus-connections-in-java-sdk-0-9-0)

We're able to connect to the azure service on public network but when i am within office network, we should go via a proxy. This is where the connection fails.

My issue is exactly the same as posted by sjohnston( above link) but I am using java sdk 0.9.7 (instead of 0.9.0 used by sjohnston)

Kindly click on the link for problem description.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

After making the changes you suggested, I got this error:

Connecting to Azure Service Bus:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.ServiceBusContract).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection timed out: connect
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.listTopics(ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.java:366)
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.Util.iterateTopics(Util.java:29)
      at com.tc.tsp.cc.controllers.TestServiceBus.configureServiceBus(TestServiceBus.java:55)
      at com.tc.tsp.cc.controllers.TestServiceBus.main(TestServiceBus.java:67)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection timed out: connect
      at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.AuthorizationFilter.handle(AuthorizationFilter.java:39)
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.core.pipeline.jersey.ClientFilterRequestAdapter.handle(ClientFilterRequestAdapter.java:35)
      at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
      at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
      at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:193)
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusRestProxy.listTopics(ServiceBusRestProxy.java:475)
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusRestProxy.listTopics(ServiceBusRestProxy.java:600)
      at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.listTopics(ServiceBusExceptionProcessor.java:362)
      ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:Connection timed out: connect
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
      at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:253)
      at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
      ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

Assumption that you are using the protocols like `AMQP` besides of `HTTP`, try to the section `2.4) SOCKS` of the Java offical document [`Java Networking and Proxies`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) to set the socks protocol proxy for your JVM to connect Azure Service Bus via proxy server.

Please add the code below at the front of the body of main function.

```
System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyHost", "<proxy-ip>");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyPort", "<proxy-port>");
```

Comment: Peter Pan, i made the changes you suggested. But still there's this error (mentioned above in the EDIT)

Comment: @PSD According to the exception, I doubt the `SOCKS` protocol not be supported in your proxy server. Could you check it? And other protocols?